# can't access Endpoint after deploy from AS , why?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, endpoint

error from GAE log :

org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler doHandle:  (ServletHandler.java:624)
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder$1: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot access service class:

Comment: does your app engine deploys correctly? is it a standard or flexible instance? is this caused when you access to your app engine url? Please provide more details of what you are encountering as well as the trouble shoot you've made

Comment: the instance is : "Serving java8 Standard "
I cannot see the instance in developer portal ,

Comment: also 
I cannot see the instance in the developer portal when i try to choice from the API list ( because there's no API to choice from).
in the log I can see the info when I try to send an Endpoint but I get those error message the action failed because :
1) org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder$1: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot access service class

2)  Cannot access service class: com.****.minddatesmudle.****.MDClientEPoints

and MDClientEPoints is public , so i really confuse.

Comment: solve , my constructor was need to be on public.